# Bash: descriptors act in a strange way

Tags: linux, bash, logging, stdout, descriptor

I am redirecting my BASH script output in a log file generated with variables and so on. 
No problem with that.
I did:

```
exec 6>&1
exec 7>&2
exec 2>&1
exec > /root/backup/report_singoli/$PNAME/$FNAME.log
```

It works flawlessy.

The problem is that sometimes i want my output to be in the "normal" stdout on the screen, so I am echoing the output in the descriptor 6, like:

```
echo "ciao prima" >&6
```

Which is woking pretty fine.

From a line to another, it wont work anymore.
I did some debug and it cames out that the problem is here:

```
echo "THIS WORKS FINE" >&6

if [ ! -f "/root/tmpfs/$PNAME/backup_end_time.txt" ]; then
    if [ -f "/root/tmpfs/$PNAME/backup_start_time.txt" ]; then
                echo ""
                echo "Il backup per l'ambiente $$FNAME - $ENVAR non è ancora completato! Salto questo ambiente..."
                echo ""
                sleep 1s
                return 0
        else
                echo ""
                echo "Sembra che l'ambiente $FNAME - $ENVAR non stia facendo alcun tipo di backup..."
                echo ""
                sleep 1s
                return 0
        fi
else
        echo ""
        echo "File semaforo verde, procediamo..."
        echo ""
        sleep 1s
fi

echo "THIS IS NOT WORKING" >&6
```

I'm wondering what's wrong with that block.

And from that point, no output works with >&6 (tough still logging in file), even when i exit from the func and i start the func over again 
(like:

```
    func random {

showing
BROKEN PART
not showing

}

random

echo "this is random!"

random
```

Even more strange, even if i reset descriptors like

```
exec 1>&6 6>&-
exec 2>&7 7>&-
```

stdout still doesnt appear on screen (normal echo "try" without ">")

Any help?

Full script here: https://pastebin.com/GdVQgETa 
WARNING: LONG AND CENSURED FOR USER AND PASSWD!

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show a complete shell script which demonstrates your problem?

Comment: did it, it's a bit long

Comment: Seems like it would be much simpler to be explicit about which code writes to `$FNAME.log` rather than making it the default standard output.

Comment: simpler for sure, also longer and dangerous if i have to modify the code and i forgot about a line..

Comment: use `echo "THIS IS NOT WORKING" > /dev/tty` if you want it to be on the screen regardless of the redirections

Comment: so nobody can find an error up there? i'll try that one btw...